# Impact of OS timezone change on Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, linux, centos

I want change OS time zone to UTC. This will shift back time by 2h. Can this possibly damage data in any way (for example overwrite data)? What should I do to safely change the OS time zone?

Comment: Depends on how your applications `INSERT` and `UPDATE` records. If there is some sort of timestamping and "most-recent-record" logic then you may have to be careful. Ideally, shut down your system for 2.5 hours and make the change then and reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set a time zone for your Postgres DB cluster in `postgresql.conf`, changing the time zone of the server OS will have no bearing on your databases at all - as long as you don't actually change the time itself, not just the time zone.

You need to make sure that none of your client programs feed *local* time to the database, which would actually change with the time zone setting of the server.

Even the time zone of the Postgres server has no bearing on data while operating with the data type `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`). Only the *display* is adjusted to the `timezone` setting of each session - which defaults to the setting of the DB cluster unless specified otherwise. But the *value* is always the same.

**However**, it matters for `timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`). And it also matters whenever a `timestamptz` is cast to `timestamp` or `date` (and the time zone is not provided explicitly with the `AT TIME ZONE` construct). This may even be hidden in expressions transforming or formatting temporal data. All of those will show an actual time-shift of two hours when the `timezone` setting of the session changes.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL timezone does not match system timezone](https://serverfault.com/questions/554359/postgresql-timezone-does-not-match-system-timezone)
- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)